# Invalid Column Name when Create trigger using SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I encountered several errors when I tried to create a simple trigger using SQL server. Tables are created using:

```
CREATE TABLE person 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    phone INT,
    birth_date DATE,
    address VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE volunteers 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    skill VARCHAR,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE physicians 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    speciality VARCHAR,
    phone_number INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE patients  
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    contact_date DATE,
    physician_id INT,   -- TODO determine whether NULL able
                        -- TODO determine ON DELETE ACTION
    CHECK (person_id <> physician_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (physician_id) REFERENCES physicians(person_id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE outpatients 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES patients(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE visits 
(
    person_id INT  NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    comments VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id, date),
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES outpatients(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE employees 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    date_hire DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE nurses 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    certificate VARCHAR,
    care_center_name VARCHAR,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES employees(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    -- FOREIGN KEY (care_center_name) REFERENCES care_centers(name)
    --     ON DELETE CASCADE
    --     ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE care_centers 
(
    name VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    nurses_in_charge INT NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR,
    type VARCHAR
    -- FOREIGN KEY (nurses_in_charge) REFERENCES registered_nurse(person_id)
);

CREATE TABLE registered_nurse 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    care_center_name VARCHAR,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES nurses(person_id),
        -- ON DELETE CASCADE
        -- ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (care_center_name) REFERENCES care_centers(name)
        -- ON DELETE CASCADE
        -- ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


ALTER TABLE nurses 
    ADD constraint nurses__care_centers_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (care_center_name) REFERENCES care_centers(name)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE care_centers 
    ADD constraint care_centers__registered_nurse_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (nurses_in_charge) REFERENCES registered_nurse(person_id);

CREATE TABLE beds 
(
    bed_number INT NOT NULL,
    room_number INT NOT NULL,
    care_center_name VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (bed_number,room_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (care_center_name) REFERENCES care_centers(name)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE residents 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    date_admitted DATE,
    bed_number INT,
    room_number INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES patients(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (bed_number, room_number) REFERENCES beds(bed_number, room_number)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE staffs 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    job_class DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES employees(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE technicians 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    skill VARCHAR,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES employees(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE laboratories 
(
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    location VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE assignTechnicianToLab 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL,
    laboratories_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(person_id, laboratories_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES employees(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (laboratories_name) REFERENCES laboratories(name)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

And the trigger I am trying to create:

```
-- Trigger
/* if nurse has certificate "RN", add to registered_nurse */
CREATE TRIGGER registered_nurse_trigger 
ON nurses
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted where certificate = "RN")
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO registered_nurse 
        VALUES(inserted.person_id, nurses.care_center_name);
    END
END;
```

And I keep getting errors saying that:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure registered_nurse_trigger, Line 6
>   Invalid column name 'RN'.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure registered_nurse_trigger, Line 8
>   The multi-part identifier "inserted.person_id" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure registered_nurse_trigger, Line 8
>   The multi-part identifier "nurses.care_center_name" could not be bound.

I've been hanging over here for several hours and I really appreciate anyone can help me with it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use single quotes for `RN`, not double quotes.

Comment: also wondering. is inserted is actual table name? or user?

Comment: @logger I thought inserted is a reserved word, representing the new row that is inserted?

Comment: @logger `inserted` is a default table that exists during an insert/update transaction.  It allows you to access the new row values, commonly in a trigger.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I mistakenly for regular operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `VALUES()` like that.  Use `INSERT..SELECT` instead:

```
-- Trigger
/* if nurse has certificate "RN", add to registered_nurse */
CREATE TRIGGER registered_nurse_trigger ON nurses
For INSERT, UPDATE
AS BEGIN
INSERT INTO registered_nurse (person_id, care_center_name)
SELECT person_id, care_center_name
FROM inserted
WHERE certificate = 'RN'
END;
```

I don't think you need to reference `nurses` or have that `EXISTS()` either, but maybe I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quote instead of single quotes in your Create Trigger statement try this and see if it works:

```
-- Trigger
/* if nurse has certificate "RN", add to registered_nurse */
CREATE TRIGGER registered_nurse_trigger ON nurses
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted where certificate = 'RN')
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO registered_nurse 
                SELECT person_id, care_center_name FROM Inserted;
        END
    END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I'm still getting "xxx could not be bound" errors. Could it be that because the table is empty?